# how to add attributes for form input directives?

Tags: angularjs

I am generating form inputs using directives. I am using ng-switch to check server validation or not. Also I am trying to use angular's validation such as required, min -max etc. How to add these attributes in the input element.

View

```
<formfield record='staff' field='fullname' live='false' validate="server"></formfield>
<formfield record='staff' field='username' live='false' ></formfield>
```

formfield template

```
    <div class="row form-group" ng-form="{{field}}" ng-class="{'has-error': {{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid}">
    <div class="input-group">

        <div class="col-md-6" ng-switch="validate">
            <input class="form-control" name='{{field}}' ng-model='record[field][0]' type='record[field][1]'
            ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' ng-switch-when="server" />
            <input class="form-control" name='{{field}}' ng-model='record[field][0]' type='record[field][1]'
            ng-switch-default/>
        </div>
        <p ng-show="{{field}}.$invalid && !{{field}}.$pristine" class="error-block">{{errors}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you be very specific in what you are asking...

Comment: in the view i have called formfield directive. It will be replaced by the formfield template and it is working. I need to add specific validation like min="3" or max="8" in the formfield which will in turn add those attributes in the input. got it?

Comment: can you put expected rather than current process, show expected html for directive & the template... you can do that with `angular.isDefined($attrs.min)` and then do if else while generating template

Comment: also there are templates which have already implemented this functionaliy, look at those if you can reuse...